# Tips for fine pitch and rugged connector

Tags: connector

I'm looking for a connector with following qualities:

- fine pitched (max 1.0 mm, preferably 0.8mm or less)
- double row
- pin count of 20 or more
- rugged design, resistant to vibrations
- relatively affordable - but quality is most important

After a long search, I found the Hirose DF50 series. DigiKey describes the following:

> " Its latch prevents uneven locking that is commonly attributed to side locks and incomplete mating. This provides security that is invaluable when dealing with high vibration and other critical applications. (https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/h/hirose/df50-board-wire-rugged-small-form-fact-conne-system)"

The DF50 series is not expensive, so it seems perfect for the job. But the crimp handtool is almost $2000 (part no. HT305/DF50-2830HC). So I end up with two questions:

- If you've ever used the DF50 series from Hirose, did you use the handtool? Perhaps one doesn't really need it..
- Do you have another favourite connector type that meets the requirements above?

Answer (score 1):

For hirose you can orsder crimped wires and ready cables. Not cheap, but for one time it's ttolerable. Look at harwin gecko an samtec tmf. I think samtec has even smaller pitch than tfm, just don't remember the series name.

Comment: For Harwin Gecko, I think I will need these two tools together: 952-2514-ND and this one 952-2515-ND. They cost about 1270 euro together. Thats' also quite expensive...

Comment: All tools are expensive. Although for samtec i bought for about 400usd. Anyway they also provide ready made cables which are always better than what i can do by myself.

Comment: That's interesting, 400$ is relatively affordable (compared to the others). Could you share the part number - both your tool and the connector series? That would be awesome :-)

Comment: Connector series is tfm. The tool is mentioned on the catalog page

Comment: The TFM/SFM series of Samtec (https://www.samtec.com/products/tfm) is only board-to-board. I don't see any product on that page with wires.. (the page is a bit unclear about that)

Comment: Ok, maybe i recalled it. Try sfsd

Comment: SFSD is the assembled cable, and TFC the connector for the board. Am I correct?

Comment: OK, just looked at my stock. The cable crimp housing is ISDF. https://www.samtec.com/products/isdf. On the catalog page there are crimps and crimpers. Be careful, don't take the orange tool. The black one requires crimps on a reel, but is much easier to operate.

Comment: I found these crimps on a reel: https://www.digikey.be/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-contacts/331?k=CC03R%2A
  Unfortunately, the minumum order quantity on DigiKey is 35.000 pieces... Where do you order them?

Comment: They have reel of 1000, i will check later. I order from their local representatives

Comment: Is this the black tool (the good one) you're referring too? CAT-HT-203-2830-12 (https://www.digikey.be/products/en?keywords=CAT-HT-203-2830-12)

Comment: Crimp: CC03M-2830-01-G. Tool:  CAT-HT-203-2830-12

Comment: One more question. The ISDF series is only the housing for the cable (the endpoint of the cable). But the site is unclear about the mating PCB connector. Is it the TFM series?

Comment: Yes, this is what i use- TFM and ISDF. I looked at website a little- no idea why they don't list them as mating parts. Anyway they are mating.

Comment: So did you get Samtec in the end?

Comment: Hi @Gregory Kornblum , Yes I got it :-)
Thanks a lot